# Call a nested package.json script

Tags: reactjs, npm, nps

So I have a package-scripts folder that holds all my scripts for building in the react environment:

```
const npsUtils = require('nps-utils')

module.exports = {
  scripts: {
    default: 'react-scripts start',
    build: 'react-scripts build',
    test: 'react-scripts test',
    eject: 'react-scripts eject',
    lint: {
      default: 'eslint ./ --ignore-path .gitignore',
      fix: 'yarn run lint -- --fix',
    },
    format: 'prettier --write "{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.js"',
    validate: npsUtils.concurrent.nps('lint', 'format', 'build'),
  },
}
```

However, when I try to call the lint fix script, it always fails. My call `yarn start lint:fix` always fails and gives the error

> Scripts must resolve to strings. There is no script that can be
> resolved from "lint:fix"

So how do i call lint fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
scripts: {
  ...
  "lint:default": "eslint ./ --ignore-path .gitignore",
  "lint:fix": "yarn run lint -- --fix",
  ...
}
```

and call it by:

```
yarn start lint:fix
```